# WebRTC Screensharing in electron not working

Tags: electron, webrtc

We have a web app to which I'm building electron app by loading URL in browserWindow. But when i try to share the screen it will give me a blank popup, Please help as i have cross the timeline

I have tried to open a link in browser for video calling but it is opening in electron itself